# WCF - Saving configuration

Tags: wcf

I'm relatively new to WCF so please forgive the rookie question. What I'm struggling with is trying to get my WCF service to remember its configuration at the service level. I'm happy that I've modified my Web.Config within my WCF project correctly, but now I want to modify the Client.dll.config and have it save. I am able to edit it happily, either by following the path directly to the file or by using the tool, but it never retains the settings. Why??

Thanks in advance
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you recompile the client solution, the Client.dll.config file is reset.  Try to update the App.config file in your client solution.

Comment: Oh I see. So are you saying that the app.config in my client is the same as what is configured via the tool on the service project? Does it override what is set on the service Client.dll.config then?

Comment: There are two sets of configurations: server which are in your web config. There are also client which tell the client where the server is.  These are stored in your app config.  Eg for a win forms app it may be in .dll.config.

Comment: Thanks Russell, yep I see that's the case, however how about the config that can be seen when you start a WCF in the windows tool and view its methods and bindings and so on - Where is that configuration stored? That is the configuration that keeps getting reverted if I change it. It seems to be, based on what you're saying, that configuration is the same as what should be present on the client.